# how to step into false condition in chrome debugger

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging

I want to step into false condition, how can I get into this. for instance.

```
if(0){
var val= some server side value
getval(va1)
}
else{
val =0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use 'debugger' and have dev tools open when you run the code. It will stop in that else statement.

```
if(0){
  var val= some server side value
  getval(va1)
}
else{
  debugger;
  val =0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution: Open the dev tools, `sources` panel. Open the file you want to debug and set a breakpoint on the line, by clicking on the left side of the panel (at the beginning of the line). Chrome will remember this breakpoints between page loads. This way it is easy to enable or disable breakpoints without having to modify the file. Chrome shows you a list of all breakpoints on the right side panel.

IE and Firefox have similar options to debug.

Comment: When you set a breakpoint, the browser will stop whenever that line is executed. If you put the breapoint inside the `else` part of your if, it will stop whenever the condition is false.

Comment: That is my question, I want to debug in false condition

Comment: ¿? I think you need to explain better. You need to debug *when your condition is false*, or you want to *force your condition to be false*?

Comment: I need to debug when my condition is false

Comment: Then any of the answers here is a valid one. Whether to use a breakpoint or the `debugger` keyword is a matter of personal tastes.

Answer (score 0):

Put a break point before the condition. Reload the page.

Use the sources panel to change (0) to (1), right click, save (cancel chrome's attempt to save the file). Advance to next function call. 
You have stepped into the false condition block.